# Boost last_write_time changes the last-write-time value

Tags: c++, boost

When I use `boost::filesystem::last_write_time(p, filetime)`, where `p` is a boost `path` and `filetime` is a `time_t`, everything works.  However, the `last_write_time` gets set to the current time, which is problematic.  Does anyone know how to prevent this function from updating the last-write-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single parameter version:

```
boost::filesystem::last_write_time(p);
```